# how to make ready queue and waiting queue

Tags: c, queue

I'm very new in C language and linux and English is not my mother language. Sorry for those in advance.

What I need to do is to make ready queue and waiting queue and to make my own thread api like thread_create, thread_self, thread_join and so on. I can't even guess how to start to make those. I just want some hint about how to make ready queue and waiting queue using linked list and how to test those.

These are all I've got for now:

-Init.h

```
#ifndef _INIT_H_
#define _INIT_H_

void Init(void);

#endif
```

-Init.c

```
#include "Init.h"
#include "Scheduler.h"
#include "Thread.h"

void Init(void)
{
//create ready queue and waiting queue
//Initialize thread scheduler
}
```

-Thread.h

```
#ifndef __THREAD_H__
#define __THREAD_H__
#include<unistd.h>

#define TIMESLICE   (2)

typedef void* (*FUNCPTR)(void* arg);
typedef pid_t   thread_t;
typedef void thread_attr_t;


typedef enum{
    THREAD_STATUS_RUN = 0,
    THREAD_STATUS_READY = 1,
    THREAD_STATUS_BLOCKED = 2,
}ThreadStatus;

typedef struct _Thread Thread;
typedef struct _Thread {
    FUNCPTR             entryPt;
    void*               stackAddr;
    int             stackSize;
    ThreadStatus            status;
    pid_t               pid;
    Thread*             pPrev;
    Thread*             pNext;
} Thread;   


/* head and tail pointers for ready queue */ 
Thread*     ReadyQHead;
Thread*     ReadyQTail;

/* head and tail pointers for waiting queue */
Thread*     WaitQHead;
Thread*     WaitQTai;


int         thread_create(thread_t *thread, thread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
int         thread_join(thread_t thread, void **retval);
int         thread_suspend(thread_t tid);
int     thread_resume(thread_t tid);
int         thread_cancel(thread_t tid);
thread_t    thread_self();

#endif /* __THREAD_H__ */
```

-Scheduler.c

```
#include "Init.h"
#include "Thread.h"
#include "Scheduler.h"

int     RunScheduler( void )
{
}     
void        _ContextSwitch(int curpid, int tpid)
{
}
```

I'm just wondering about init.c part and I added other codes to make my question understand easier. Please give me some hint. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by own API? do you want to write function that works like pthread_create()?

Comment: @SumitGemini yes exactly. But I can't even guess how to start on Init.c in the first place

Comment: for this purpose you have to use RTLD_NEXT() function. initialize your function pointer like: thread_create is your function pointer. thread_create should have exect parameter that pthread_create has.
thread_create = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"pthread_self);

init.c you have to perform only this kind of operation for all function which you want to create.